# Setting Java Environment in Centos/Red Hat on startup

Tags: java, installation

Good morning,

I've been searching how to set the Java environment upon restart on a non-root user. I have a file set in rc3.d and rc5.d that won't run on startup (after a reboot). I'm wondering if this is because the Java environment is not set on startup. While I'm in the terminal, I have to manually set the Java Environment every time before I run my .sh files. So the breakdown is:

1. How can I set my .sh files to automatically run after a reboot?
2. How can I set my Java Environment permanently? (I'm not sure if I edited my .bash_profile correct)

   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/home/usr/java/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:/home/usr/java/bin
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/usr/java

Some key info: I do not have access to login as root. The Red Hat system admin gave me sudo. So any /etc files and root files I edit via "sudo vi [file name]".

I'm obviously a beginner, so forgive me for asking a question I'm sure has been answered 1000 times.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install Java?

Comment: @ernest_k I downloaded the JDK package (jdk-8u171-linux-i586.tar.gz) from Oracle and unpacked the file:

tar zxf jdk-8u.....

to unpack the contents to my user folder. From there, I created a softlink to that folder:

ln -s /usr/jdk-8u<ver>-linux-i586  /usr/java

From there, I'm lost. Ever since then, whenever I want to run my .sh files, I would first instantiate my JAVA_HOME:

export JAVA_HOME=/home/usr/java

and then I'd run my file.